# Javascript: array of objects VS object with unique properties?

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, indexing, socket.io

I'm working in a real-time web application for my company, and I'm using MEAN stack with socket.io to provide real-time $scope variable updates in all clients in a specific socket room.

I'm currently using an array of objects that is dynamic, being able to add or remove elements, and I have to set a $watch function for each array element and pass the element's _id in it's respective $watch function. The problem is: AngularJS can't keep track of element's position in array by it's _id as elements are removed.

So I was considering, instead of using an array to store objects, use an object with unique properties that are each element's id, like this:

```
$scope.mainObj = {
   '1234': {name: 'bob', age: 21},
   '1235': {name: 'william', age: 23},
   '1236': {name: 'rob', age: 28}
};
```

instead of:

```
$scope.mainArray = [
   {_id: '1234', name: 'bob', age: 21},
   {_id: '1235', name: 'william', age: 23},
   {_id: '1236', name: 'rob', age: 28}
];
```

At first, I think this would remove the problem of having to index my array and having to locate the element's position in every client in a room to update a variable, making the changes atomic by updating the property named after element's _id.

Would this bring any performance issue or another problem? Like I said, array indexes would be dispensable, lookup functions to detect the element by _id wouldn't be necessary and the chances of updating the wrong element would be 0, as using the indexed array approach exists a minimal chance of the wrong element be updated when too many users are adding, removing or editing array elements.

So, is it a good idea? If not, how could I $watch array elements, pass the element _id in watch function and don't lose track of each element? What I have now is this:

```js
$scope.setWatch = function (element, id) {
  $scope.$watch(x, function() {
    console.log('watching: ' + element);
    console.log('do something with : ' + id);
  });
}

socket.on('addArrayElm', function (res) {
  var id = res.id;
  $scope.mainArray.push(new arrayElement(id));//creates new element from constructor with received _id from server
  $scope.mainArrayIndex.push(id);//push id in index array
  var i = $scope.mainArrayIndex.length - 1;//get the pushed element index in array
  var j = 'mainArrayIndex[' + i + '].name';//construct string to use in $watch function referring to the element in array's position 'i'
  $scope.setWatch(j, z);
  $scope.$apply();
});
```

The main problem is: if I remove an element, like the second one (index = 1), the $watch function is not destroyed, and as it took the index = 1 as a parameter, it's going to be triggered for the element that took index = 1, so the wrong _id is used.

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Stick with the array of objects and use `ng-repeat="item in mainArray track by item._id"`. Under the hood Angular uses `$watchCollection` and it works fine.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer!

The main problem is that I must know exactly which object changed, and trigger a function only when some properties change, not all properties, so I can improve performance. If I use the watchCollection approach, this function will run for any property change.

For example, my object has the properties "name", "age","address", "x", "y", "z", "w".

I have to trigger a function only if "x", "y" or "z" changes, not all properties, and this function returns property "w" in real time particularly for this object.

Comment: I don't think you understand how `$watchCollection` works. Review [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope `$watch` Performance Considerations](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-watch-performance-considerations).

Comment: @georgeawg, thanks again!

Well, as I know, and as Angular docs says, $watchCollection won't trigger when array element property changes, and this is exactly what I need. I would need to use "$watch, true" to detect changes is element properties, but my function would be triggered in any property change, not only when "x", "y" or "z" changes, like I said... and I'd have to locate the correct element by it's _id in array to calculate it's "w" property.

Am I missing something here??

Comment: I can't see how $watchCollection can help me in this situation. The most suitable solution that I can imagine is to set a simple $watch for each single property as I add new elements, like:

$scope.mainObj = {
   '1234': {name: 'bob', age: 21},
   '1235': {name: 'william', age: 23},
   '1236': {name: 'rob', age: 28}
};
$scope.setWatch('mainObj .' + '1234' + '.x', '1234');

And like this I only have to $watch for changes in "mainObj .1234.x"

Comment: I can't use the ng-repeat="item in mainArray track by item._id" approach to set the $watches because my app has tabs defined by a ng-if condition, so there are areas that this ng-repeat won't exist, neither the watches, and these changes must be detected even if the current tab is not active.

Comment: Avoid using the $scope $watch API to implement business logic in controllers. Watchers should only be used to update the DOM from changes in the model. The controller should fully update the model without the help of watchers.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @georgeawg, thank you very much for your considerations!

Now I think I understood the main goal of watchers... I should trigger all calculations manually as changes are made to a model, not watching variables and relying on it's callbacks to proceed with calculations...

Well, this makes sense, as I'll save resources as no watchers will be necessary.

Thank you again!